# Solving $ \dot N = N \left( f - \frac{M}{K} a(t) \right) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \dot N = N \left( f - \frac{M}{K} a(t) \right) $$

I have been struggling to solve this differential equation for $N(t)$ for hours now. Could anyone please provide me with some help?

Comment: What is $a(t)$?

Comment: Have you tried dividing both sides by $N$?

Comment: And multiply both sides by dt.

Answer (score 1):

You have a differential equation of the form $\dot f(t)=h(t)f(t)$, which you can rewrite as $\frac{\dot f}{f}=h$. And since $\frac{\dot f}{f}$ is the derivative of $\ln(f)+C$, you get $\ln(f)+C=H$, where $H$ is a primitive of $h$. Now you just have to solve for $f$.